Cache Issue with Angular Web Application
We have an angular(v9) web application for insurance policy holders to login and manage their policies. Recently, we deployed a new change, however, many of the customers don't see the change.
We have set response header and configurations as follows.
Response Header:
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, no-revalidate
Configuration in angular.json
configurations: {
production: {
outputHashing: 'all'
}
}
Service worker implementation that alerts if any new version of the application available. Application will be reloaded if user confirms the prompt.
Is there a way users get the latest changes without clearing browser cache?

There are many ways, but the recommend way is to use Cache Bustsing. Normally Angular set config to create each file (in build process) with an unique hash code in the file name. To check if so, have a look to the Angular.json file in your project and check is outputHashing set to all:
// angular.json
 {
 "projects": {
 "your-project": {
 "architect": {
 "build": {
 "options": {
 "outputHashing": "all"
.....

In Angular 9 you can do this by hand within the build command:
ng build --prod --output-hashing=all

In the end the files in the dist folder should look like this:
...
main.6785167b3be88a1b.js
...

Why is this working:
With this each file name has a unique name in the html file and the browser will detect the files "as new" bypassing the cache. So each new deployed version will be showed correctly to the user.
Additional ideas:
Add some meta tags inside your index.html:
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

These tags tell the browser not to cache the page. However, this method is less reliable than cache busting.
The last way is to set header directly on the web server, like this: Cache-Control: no-cache

At the end of the day, Angular's cache busting will be the best option. Setting the web server (header) or using the meta tags achieves the same result at first glance, but with both of these the browser always reloads the entire website and completely ignores the cache.
With cache busting, this will only happen when the page is updated - which promotes the fast performance you expect.

Thanks, Flo for reply. We have all these things you mentioned here are in out application. outputHasing technique and cache-control headers were added to the application 1.5 years ago. We doubt that people who have accessed the application before we added these are facing this issue. From F5 logs, we observed that, when they login, there is no request reaches to web server, however, API calls are being triggered.
